# How can OAuth2 in SPA + Web API app be implemented?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

There is an app with Angular 10 on frontend and ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API on backend. I need to add ability for user to login via GitHub and Google without using logins and passwords. What's the right flow for this process? Are there some examples of implementing such thing?

I have one working solution, but the problem with it is sending user data and access token from backend to frontend.

Comment: @Yurri - **without using logins and passwords** - do you mean that the user should be able to login without being prompted to enter user credentials.If that is the case what you should be looking at is oauth2 client credentials flow , I am afraid this flow is not recommend/supported for SPA its intended to be used for Daemon apps i.e. server to server calls

Answer (score 0):

**FLOW TO USE**

The standard flow for an SPA is to use Authorization Code Flow (PKCE), which results in messages from [my blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/).

**WITHOUT LOGINS AND PASSWORDS**

I know what you mean here: user logs in via familiar password if not logged in already.

**CONNECTING THE MOVING PARTS**

My [index page](https://authguidance.com/home/mainindex/) has some step by step code samples, though I do not cover social logins yet.

**INFRASTRUCTURE**

Usually you start with a Cloud Authorization Server (eg Azure AD) which has its own default login option for users without Google / GitHub accounts. The AS can also federate to Google / GitHub when required.

**FEDERATION**

Here is an example of [Federating from Azure AD to GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/github-tutorial).

**ARCHITECTURE GOALS**

- Once Azure AD is set up, you won't need to change any code in your UIs and APIs to support a different login method
- Regardless of login method, your API will identify users and their data after login via a consistent user id